# Comparing different Pandas dataframes using nested for-loops

Tags: python, pandas

I'm comparing 2 pandas dataframes columns trying to find a substring match using nested for loops. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Here is my actual code:

```
c = 0
for i, sisRow in sis.iterrows():
    for e, sapRow in sap.iterrows():
        codSis = sisRow['prod_Codigo']
        codSap = sapRow['ItemCode']
        if codSap.find(codSis) != -1:
            sis.loc[i, 'desc_SAP'] = sapRow['ItemName']
            sis.loc[i, 'prod_CodigoSap'] = sapRow['ItemCode']
            sap.drop(sap.index[e])
            c += 1
            print(c, end=', ')
            break
```

I am using the print statement just to keep track that the program is running and I didn't end up inside an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of iterating rows, you can iterate a series mapping and use Boolean indexing column-wise.

```
sap_map = sapRow.set_index('ItemCode')['ItemName']

for k, v in sap_map.items():
    mask = [codSis in k for codSis in sisRow['prod_Codigo'].values]
    sis.loc[mask, 'desc_SAP'] = v
    sis.loc[mask, 'prod_CodigoSap'] = k
```

It's not clear why you are removing items from an iterator as you iterate, i.e. `sap.drop(...)`. This is not recommended practice and it's not clear what this is achieving. Therefore, I have omitted this step. It does mean that you may wish to order your mapping series, otherwise later mappings will take priority.